# TYPO3 v11: parse <link> tags

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-11.x

I'm currently upgrading a TYPO3 v9 to v11. There I use the table content element in combination with  tags. E.g. something like this:

```
Some Text with an <link https://domain.tld>external link</link>
```

In TYPO3 v9 I used this to get real links in the table:

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">{cell}</f:format.html>
```

But in v11 the link is not parsed correctly. Output is:

```
<link https: domain.tld>external link
```

So the double slash and the closing `</link>` are gone.

I tried to use a custom parseFunc where I disabled `htmlSanitize`. Then the `<link>` tag stays intact, but isn't parsed at all.

Any ideas how I can get `<link>` work again? Or is there any other way to use links in the table content element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<link>` is old Syntax and migrated already in v8. However, this was still partly able in v9.

See: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Deprecation-83252-Link-tagSyntaxProcesssing.html#deprecation-83252-link-tag-syntax-processsing

You should properly migrate your content to the new Syntax before upgrade. In v9 the corresponding UpgradeWizard should still be there, in v11 not.

From core side you cannot get it working again as core dropped this Syntax. Better migrate your content properly.

Comment: Thx a lot for your link, I tried to google it prior to asking my question but apparently I didn't found it. So I need to use HTML links in the table content element since there is no RTE available. But turning off `htmlSanitize` is not necessary.